# Word VBA: Insertbefore numbered list paragraph and before item 1

Tags: html, vba, ms-word

This feels like it should have a simple answer, but I can't find it.  As part of an effort to convert hundreds of word documents to plain HTML, I'm using vba to crawl the documents and add the appropriate tags. List paragraphs are presenting a problem, because inserting the tag before each list drops it in on the first line (i.e. it bumps item #1 down, and the new item is "1.").  The insert after method works just fine for the end of the list.  The VBA is pasted below. Any ideas? Thanks

```
Sub listparagraphtagging()
    Dim aList As list
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each aList In ActiveDocument.Lists
        aList.Range.InsertParagraphBefore
        aList.Range.InsertBefore "<ul>"
        aList.Range.InsertAfter "</ul>"
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, a bit late to the party but give this a go :)

```
Sub listparagraphtagging()
    Dim aList As List
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim para As Paragraph

    For Each aList In ActiveDocument.Lists
        For Each para In aList.Range.Paragraphs
            Set rng = para.Range
            rng.InsertBefore "<ul>"
            rng.End = rng.End - 1
            rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            rng.Text = "</ul>"
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```